# Mapping KVM guest VMs to subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kvm

I've just installed KVM on a Ubuntu host system and intend to install two guest VMs on it. I have a domain, e.g. `example.com`. How can I configure my system so that VM(a) is accessible by `example.com` and VM(b) is accessible by `internal.example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the VM's have publically accessible ip addresses (that's a different question) you will want to contact whoever manages the example.com dns server and provide those ip addresses so that they can add these two systems to it.